# ASP.NET IIS and framework

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have one ASP.NET web application projrct, created in Visual Studio 2008, .NET 3.5 Framework, IIS 6.1 and I'm using Ajax updatepanel, cache options for caching the datatable in a gridview. This project is working good in local, but when I deployed in a cert environment (.NET Framework 2.0 and IIS 6.0) I faced that caching issue.

So that, now I'm trying to change the project from 3.5 to 2.0 framework. But I'm facing an Ajax update panel error.

How can this problem be fixed?

Comment: "please help what i have to do" ... You have to supply a little more information. Specifically, what "caching issue" are you having? I'm assuming your grid view is not updating properly but without better information it's a little difficult to give you any help.

Comment: first im binding 1 to 200 rows with the page size of 20 so, totaly 20 pages, then im using a button to set diff range like 1 to 60 with page size of 10 so,totaly 6 pages now but, im getting more than 6 pages that is the previous 20 pages...  my paging looses the the correct data....

Answer (score 0):

You mean the target framework? You can right click the application name and then click on Property Pages, in that go to Build and then choose the target framework to 2.0.

Also, have a look at this:
http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398791(VS.90).aspx
reference : http://forums.asp.net/t/1194067.aspx

It will not be very straight forward though. As there may be some language features that are only available in 3.5.

Comment: thanks for ur quick reply.... while coverting im getting this three erors..The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Xml' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

The type or namespace name 'ScriptManager' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.UI' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    

The type or namespace name 'ScriptManager' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.UI' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NEt AJAX framework for ASP.NET 2.0 has a separate DLL you have to install manually from this link: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ca9d90fa-e8c9-42e3-aa19-08e2c027f5d6&displaylang=en

You'll have to use an older version of the AJAX control toolkit too; the latest is only supported on 3.5 and 4.0.

HTH.